Trying to write out a csv file from within IBM FIleNet P8 CPE Search
I am trying to do a search in IBM FileNet's ACCE and I want to use a Javascript module to write out some property values. I can get the search to run but the writing of the values eludes me. My programming days are way behind me. So asking for some help.
The only thing I have been able to get to work is to write the output to WebSphere's SystemOut.log but I don't want it there.
What am I missing?
Thank you
importClass(java.lang.System);
importClass(Packages.com.filenet.api.property.Properties);
importClass(java.io.FileOutputStream);

function OnCustomProcess (CEObject)
{
    CEObject.refresh();
    var out = new FileOutputStream("D://Temp/test_cpe_script.out");
    var props = CEObject.getProperties();
    var docTitle = CEObject.getProperties().getStringValue("DocumentTitle");
    System.out.println(docTitle);
    out.write(docTitle);      // THIS IS WHAT DOES NOT WORK
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}


As the script executes on the server, the path given must be a valid path on the server.

Maybe do it from a client pc either with powershell, c# or java.
Connect with the client sdk to
http://myserver:9080/wsi/FNCEWS40MTOM.wsdl
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/filenet-p8-platform/5.5.11?topic=started-getting-procedures#gs_procedures__gs_procedures_get_connection
